# Setting values to fields

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I created a plugin counting the number of records of an entity related to another one, if there is more than one record, I retrieve the last record. If that record is inactive and a specific field's value >0, then I add the value of this field to the newly created one...But can't get it to work...

Any help would be great !

**Edit:** 
The plugin is registered to "new_lignecontrat" wich contains the attributes "new_unitesutilisees" and "new_unitesrestantes".

**Edit 2:**

Ok solved it ! All I needed was simply to get an EntityReference for the lookup field and rearrange a bit my code...

Thanks for your help !

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class StatusContrat : IPlugin
    {         
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Instanciation des services
            IPluginExecutionContext context     = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service        = factory.CreateOrganizationService(null);

            Entity statusEntité = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                    // Récupération des lignes de contrat liées au contrat courant
                FetchExpression fetch   = new FetchExpression("<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical'>" +
               "<entity name='new_contrats'>" +
               "<link-entity name='new_lignecontrat' alias='nombreligne' from='new_contratsid' to='new_contratsid'>" +
               "</link-entity>" +
               "</entity>" +
               "</fetch>");

                EntityCollection lines = service.RetrieveMultiple(fetch);

                    // Vérification qu'il y a au moins une ligne de contrat associée
                    if (lines.Entities.Count > 0)
                    {   
                        if (lines.Entities.Last().GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value == 1)
                        {
                           if (lines.Entities.Last().GetAttributeValue<float>("new_unitesrestantes")<0)
                           {
                              var unitesRestantes = (statusEntité.GetAttributeValue<float>("new_unitesrestantes")) + (lines.Entities.Last().GetAttributeValue<float>("new_unitesrestantes"));
                              var unitesUtilisee =  (statusEntité.GetAttributeValue<float>("new_unitesutilisees")) - (lines.Entities.Last().GetAttributeValue<float>("new_unitesutilisees"));

                                statusEntité ["new_unitesutilisees"] = unitesUtilisee;
                                statusEntité ["new_unitesrestantes"] = unitesRestantes;

                                service.Update(statusEntité);
                           }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        statusEntité["new_unitesutilisees"] = "0";
                        statusEntité["new_unitesrestantes"] = statusEntité["new_unitestotales"];

                        service.Update(statusEntité);
}                        

         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Accented characters in C# variable names always makes me laugh. Don't know why, it's just so unnatural.

Comment: Actually, it is unnatural to me as well. Just did it without thinking. Bad habit taken from my teacher.

Comment: Do you get any error message or output at all? What happens at the moment?

Comment: Nope, no error messages...Nothing happens. I have no problem creating a new record but my fields don't change.

Comment: @MademoiselleLenore Are you calling service.SaveChanges() anywhere? this is what actually updates the DB.

Comment: Hi Jon ! Well...No, but just done it. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

**Q:** Are you sure your plugin is being executed at all? 
To check this, you could alter the code to throw an InvalidPluginExecutionException somewhere so you know its at least executing.

**Q:** Is your plugin registered correctly? 
Check to see if your plugin is registered on the Create message and in either of the Pre-Validation or Pre-Operation steps.

**Q:** Is your plugin executing along the path you'd expect? 
 
I'd suggest you perform some debugging on the server (assuming you're doing your dev on-premise)

**Edit:**

I just realized that you are trying to update your target entity using a service call. When a plugin needs to update the fields on the primary entity of that plugin, it only needs to modify the attributes on the Target during either Pre-Validation or Pre-Operation stages.

```
        Entity target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

        // Récupération des lignes de contrat liées au contrat courant
        FetchExpression fetch = new FetchExpression(@"
            <fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical'>
              <entity name='new_contrats'>
                <link-entity name='new_lignecontrat' alias='nombreligne' from='new_contratsid' to='new_contratsid'>
                </link-entity>
              </entity>
            </fetch>");

        // Note: Do you need some attribute fields so that the entities are actually returning some relevant data
        // Note: Do you want to retrieve ALL the 'new_contrats' or should you be adding a condition in here to the primary entity?
        //  <filter type='and'>
        //    <condition attribute='MyIdFieldHere' operator='eq' value='" + context.PrimaryEntityId + "' /> 
        //  </filter>

        EntityCollection lines = service.RetrieveMultiple(fetch);

        // Vérification qu'il y a au moins une ligne de contrat associée
        if (lines.Entities.Any())
        {
            // store last entity in variable so that the collection is enumerabled 4 seperate times
            var last = lines.Entities.Last();
            if (last.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value == 1)
            {
                if (last.GetAttributeValue<float>("new_unitesrestantes") < 0)
                {
                    var unitesRestantes = (target.GetAttributeValue<float>("new_unitesrestantes")) + (last.GetAttributeValue<float>("new_unitesrestantes"));
                    var unitesUtilisee = (target.GetAttributeValue<float>("new_unitesutilisees")) - (last.GetAttributeValue<float>("new_unitesutilisees"));

                    target["new_unitesutilisees"] = unitesUtilisee;
                    target["new_unitesrestantes"] = unitesRestantes;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // if 'new_unitesutilisees' is a float, then the value must also be a float
            target["new_unitesutilisees"] = 0f; 
            target["new_unitesrestantes"] = target["new_unitestotales"];
        }
```

**Edit 2:**

Also, I'm assuming there is a better fetch query to run instead of retrieving all entities, then only using the last one. Could you narrow down the retrieved list by adjusting the query to set a reverse order and retrieve only the first item? Depending on how many entities in the system, this little optimization will greatly reduce the execution time of this plugin.

Comment: Hi Luke and thanks for your answer.

R: The plugin is executed and registered correctly.
I applied your changes but still nothing.
2 things though:
- it seems the "else" is never reached...
- when I try to add an attribute, I get the following error : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: Ok, get my problem now. It's indeed my fetchXml. Problem is I'm trying to use a filter to compare new_contrats.contratsid(primary key) to new_contrat.contratsid (lookup field) and of course get an xml error. Any idea of how to do it? I'm stuck and didn't find a lot of things on the internet. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: I'm happy to help but need more information about your requirements. What is the name of the entity which this plugin is registered to? (new_contrats or new_lignecontrat?) Which entity do these two attributes belong to ('new_unitesutilisees' and 'new_unitesrestantes')? If you want you can modify your question to answer these questions.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the code you're using, it could be because your `FetchXML` doesn't retrieve any attributes, particularly the attributes `new_unitesrestantes` and `new_unitesutilisees`, so any entities retrieved by the `RetrieveMultiple` request wouldn't have values for those attributes.

```xml
<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical'>
  <entity name='new_contrats'>
    <!-- no attributes listed here -->
    <link-entity name='new_lignecontrat' alias='nombreligne' from='new_contratsid' to='new_contratsid'>
      <!-- no attributes listed here either -->
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```